# Prestashop import categories by csv with id custom

Tags: php, csv, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on prestashop and need to setup categories and subs categories but I'm failling on the following error:

```
Errors occurred:
L'identifiant de la catégorie doit être unique. Il ne peut être le même que celui des catégories racine et Accueil.
```

here you will find some datas from the csv file:

```
ID;Active (0/1);Name *;Parent category;Root category (0/1);Description
30000;1;Enfant;;0;Vous trouverez ici tout les articles de mode pour votre enfant
Cette categorie inclut tout les articles de votre garde robe et bien plus:
Chaussures, accessoires, vetements, bijoux, etc..
10000;1;Femme;;0;Vous trouverez ici tout les articles de mode pour la femme.
Cette categorie inclut tout les articles de votre garde robe et bien plus:
Chaussures, accessoires, vetements, bijoux, etc..
20000;1;Homme;;0;Vous trouverez ici tout les articles de mode pour l'homme
Cette categorie inclut tout les articles de votre garde robe et bien plus:
Chaussures, accessoires, vetements, bijoux, etc..
40000;1;Meuble - Deco;;0;Vous trouverez ici tout les articles de decoration pour votre maison
Cette categorie inclut tout les articles pour votre maison et bien plus:
Tableau, horloge, bougies, mobilier, instruments de musique etc�
30100;1;bijoux;30000;0;Selectionnez votre bonheur parmi notre catalogue de bijoux
30200;1;chaussures;30000;0;Trouvez votre bonheur parmi notre catalogue de chaussures
30300;1;coiffure;30000;0;Trouvez ici vos accessoires de coiffure
30500;1;vetements;30000;0;Votre garde robe est ouverte ...
10100;1;bijoux;10000;0;Selectionnez votre bonheur parmi notre catalogue de bijoux
10200;1;chaussures;10000;0;Trouvez votre bonheur parmi notre catalogue de chaussures
10300;1;coiffure;10000;0;Trouvez ici vos accessoires de coiffure
10400;1;Sac;10000;0;Trouvez votre sac !
10500;1;vetements;10000;0;Votre garde robe est ouverte ...
20100;1;bijoux;20000;0;Selectionnez votre bonheur parmi notre catalogue de bijoux
20200;1;chaussures;20000;0;Trouvez votre bonheur parmi notre catalogue de chaussures
20300;1;coiffure;20000;0;Trouvez ici vos accessoires de coiffure
20400;1;Sac;20000;0;Trouvez votre sac !
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Br,

JRosette

Answer (score 0):

I try to upload the file and I have a problem with the first 4 categories, because the descriptions have line breaks (at least when I copy directly from your answer.) like the image:

[image]

I try to format this to a one line, then I try to import and works fine for me.

Only select this two options:

[image]

In the next step you can check if the fields are correctly formatted:

[image]

This is based about the problem is the break lines, if you don't have this problem (it's probably because the error code it's different) only try to select the option named "Forze ID number's" to yes. Also, you can send us a image of the step that you can check the fields (2nd step).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Addis, Thanks for our reply. I found where was the problem the file was encoded in UTF16. I don't know why maybe because of powershell coding.